# Create merge request from Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can I create a merge request from GitLab CI?

I could try to call the API, but I read that there is no write access unless you add a personal token.

Any other way to do this?

Comment: You can also get a project access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personal token should be the preferred way of doing it.

As it will be needed to imitate you to create the merge request and perform any action.

Comment: So a personal access token of the admin account?

Comment: There is project specific access token.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html

You may have a specific token, dedicated for a particular project